# Are there any languages with "lateral" assignment operators?

Tags: operator-keyword, mirror

I don't know a really good name for what I'm talking about, but, most programming languages use a syntax for assignment statements something like this:

(variable) (assignment operator) (expression)

And some have some special assignment operators, such as `var1 += var2` which is equivalent to`var1 = var1 + var2`.

My question is basically, is there any language that would treat += like above, but also have an =+ operator so that `var1 =+ var2` would be equivalent to `var2 = var2 + var1`?

Essentially, are there programming languages with "mirrorable" assignment operators, so that the variable on the right is what gets assignment a new variable (as opposed to the one on the left)?

Edit:

I suppose a much better example of what I'm referring to would be a language in which you can have both `(variable) (assignment operator) (expression)` and `(expression) (assignment operator) (variable)` as valid statements.

Comment: So you want something like x = y + z to be also written as y + z = x ? what is the value of having this ?

Comment: There isn't, I guess? I just know that, traditionally, the variable goes on the left side. And, considering some of the more esoteric languages out there, I can't really imagine there not being one that supports this.

Comment: Yeah it's hard to describe that as lateral, backwards would be nearer. Can't think of a single situation where such a facility would allow me to express myself better.

Comment: To the heartless creature who proposed a vote to put this on hold, due to it being "primarily opinion based": how is this based on opinion, if all we are stating here are facts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authors of programming languages usually try to keep their language as simple as possible, without any unnecessary redundancy. So having any kind of two-side evaluation is redundant and unnecessary. It will only make the language specification 20 pages longer. I think there is no language with this feature.

By the way, your "grammar" (syntax rules) is not clear. What if someone writes

```
var x = 3, y = 2;
x = y;
```

By the way, Pascal has a "direction" of assignment. Actually, you can write your code as

```
var x = 3, y = 2;
x := y;
y =: x;
```

and write your own simple preprocessor for that, but again, I think it is just a complication of "clean" language.

Comment: Well, if I were designing such a language, most likely, I wouldn't use the "=" operator. I'd have perhaps a ".=" operator (for when the variable is on the left) and a "=." (for when the variable is on the right).

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph, but your first code example could be solved if you had a rule for ambiguity: left to right always having the preference in such cases, for example.

Comment: @IvanKuckir people who believe in obfuscation as a form of security would have an orgasm after reading tour preprocessor suggestion. But even though I now hate you for potentially having brought a new wave of Pascal/Delphi obfuscation rage, I still wish I could upvote you multiple times, though, as that's just pure evil genius.

Answer (score 3):

What you propose is **just a way to make code harder to read**. There is no value in having a `=+` operator if it's just *synthatic sugar* for writing your variables *in a different order*. But since you're into this weird stuff, you would surely love languages like [Befunge](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge) and [Piet](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Piet), which, in a somewhat twisted way, do support that.

Comment: He hasn't proposed anything. He's asking whether it's been done. -1

Answer (score 1):

Some COBOL instructions are like this. E.g. `ADD B TO A` is the equivalent of "A += B" in other languages.